# If these equals... then what number is "?"

Tags: cipher, pattern

If,

7∆ + 11□ - 2□ + 1∆ = 36

12∆ - 8∆ + 8□ + 2∆ = 25

3□ + 17∆ + 5□ + 2∆= 289

then,

1□ + 7□ + 2□ + 3∆ + 17∆ = ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1

because

> triangle means multiplying by 3, square means multiplying by 4. The answer is the sum of the digits of the result squared.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty far fetched but:

> Is it... 324 because you add all the numbers in the line before the equal sign and you take away the sum of the squares +2 (and +1 if the numbers contains non-primes) and then square the result?

Comment: I would laugh if this was right

Comment: Not the correct answer.. I can say, the logic is much more simpler